# Slider con imágenes y videos asociados a base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, video, slider

Tengo una página la cual contiene un slider de imágenes, las imágenes están alojadas en una base de datos MYSQL el código del slider es el siguiente

```
<div class="container-items">
                                    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($Barco->dataBarco[0]->galeria);$i++){ ?>
                                        <div class="item" rel="1" id="item2-<?php print $i+1; ?>">
                                            <a href="ui/galery/galery-barcos/<?php print $Barco->dataBarco[0]->galeria[$i]->imagen; ?>" class="image fancybox" title="<?php print $Barco->dataBarco[0]->galeria[$i]->alt; ?>" data-fancybox-group="thumb">
                                                <img src="ui/galery/galery-barcos/<?php print $Barco->dataBarco[0]->galeria[$i]->imagen; ?>" alt="<?php print $Barco->dataBarco[0]->galeria[$i]->alt; ?>"/>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?>                              
                                </div>
```

Lo que quiero es llamar un video que debo poner en la base de datos pero no se que parámetros utilizar para realizar esa función.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

https://varietycruises.crucemar.com/update-variety-2020/adriatico-y-grecia.itinerario#barco esa es la página donde esta el slider en la sección barco.

GRACIAS!!

Comment: No se termina de entender en qué ocupas ayuda

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no se como poner el video en ese código, ya que si lo dejo como está no me funciona, no se visualiza en la página, simplemente muestra el espacio del video pero no lo reproduce ni nada

Comment: En la consola sale algún error?

Comment: Si, puedes visualizarlo en https://varietycruises.crucemar.com/update-variety-2020/adriatico-y-grecia.itinerario#barco